# mysqldump merge for rows

Tags: sql, merge, mysql, database-replication

I am using mysqldump for replicating one table to other server. Everytime I start the process, mysqldump brings all inserts of data in table.

For example, let's say I have 1 record in the table and I don't have a primary key on this table.

I use `--no-create-info` option currently to dump all inserts only data.

1st run i got 1 record
2nd run i got 2 record
...
and so on

What I need is a kind of merge action if it's possible with mysqldump.

so result should be

1st run i got 1 record
2nd run i got 1 record

after new inserted record

3rd run i should have 2 records

Thanks.

Comment: If the purpose is just to update the second server you can set mysql replication. Other option would be to set a trigger that will insert / update the second server - not sure if this will work - i haven't tried.

Comment: replication is not allowed in shared server trigger cant connect to remote sql

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page, http://shiplu.mokadd.im/110/splitting-huge-mysql-dump-for-easy-restore/ it shows various ways of splitting a dump of a single table.

I haven't had time to try this yet and you may need to add '--no-create-info' to the commands, I'd be interested to know your final solution if you use any of the methods on that page.

OK I had time to try splitting a big table, 13 Million records, into three files because my server was having trouble with the single file. The following worked for me.

mysqldump --host=localhost --user=user --password=password --where "1 LIMIT 0, 5000000" db_name table_name > table_name_01.sql

mysqldump --host=localhost --user=user --password=password --where "1 LIMIT 5000000, 5000000" --no-create-info db_name table_name > table_name_02.sql

mysqldump --host=localhost --user=user --password=password --where "1 LIMIT 10000000, 5000000" --no-create-info db_name table_name > table_name_03.sql